# Cambiar formato de fechas en datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

Mi problema es el siguiente, desde la base de datos recibo las fechas indicadas en la siguiente imagen (con el formato de dmy)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al recibirla en el datepicker la toma en otro formato
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esto hace que en esta fecha no pueda mostrarla pues piensa que es del 06 del mes 21, 2018 (fecha que no existe)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date" name="date" uib-datepicker-popup="{{Reportes.format}}" ng-model="Reportes.alumnObtain.fecha_nac" is-open="Reportes.opened" min-date="Reportes.minDate" max-date="'2019-12-22'" uib-datepicker-options="Reportes.dateOptions"
                               date-disabled="Reportes.disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="Reportes.open($event)">
                                <em class="fa fa-calendar"></em>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    @*<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="Reportes.alumnObtain.fecha_nac" />*@
                </div>
```

datepicker

```
        table.today = function() {
            table.dt = new Date();
        };
        table.today();

        table.clear = function () {
            table.dt = null;
        };

        // Disable weekend selection
        table.disabled = function(date, mode) {
            return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
        };

        table.toggleMin = function() {
            table.minDate = table.minDate ? null : new Date();
        };
        table.toggleMin();

        table.open = function ($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            table.opened = true;
        };

        table.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1
        };

        table.initDate = new Date('2019-10-20');
        table.format = 'dd/MMMM/yyyy';


        //end datepicker
```

Espero puedan ayudarme :)

Comment: Cómo seteas ese `Reportes.format`?

Comment: `angular.module('App')
.controller('ReportesController', function ($state, $scope, $http, $compile, $window, $timeout, $resource) {
             
var table = this;

table.format = 'dd/MMMM/yyyy';
}`

Comment: Me refería a cuando asignas `uib-datepicker-popup="{{Reportes.format}}"`... porque sólo deberías especificar que formato de fecha quieres y se mostrará así `uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd'`, etc

Comment: Ya lo había intentado de esa manera, lo tenia así por que en el plugin original tenia una lista de formatos, y se escogía el format[0] de esa lista, pero ya vi donde estaba mi error, ya que cuando recibía la fecha en javascript con formato dd-mm-yyyy creo una nueva variable para hacer la conversion con new Date();.

Esta pregunta me ayudo a resolver mi problema, agradezco tambien tu ayuda Paulo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object/33299764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto funciono para mi, espero sirva para cualquier pregunta similar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299687/how-to-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-into-javascript-date-object/33299764